# DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader customization

Tags: database-schema, dbix-class, perl

We have a MyISAM DB (don't ask me why we don't switch to InnoDB, it is not controlled by me).

Now I want `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` to create relationships for `*ID` columns adding `s` to get table names. For example, `Order.SeanceID` should relate table `Order` with table `Seances`.

Can `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` be hacked to do this? Or is it better to write my own Loader?

Comment: Are you planning to change the schema often? Do you have a lot of tables? Would it not make sense to add the relationships once after you've Loadered the classes? If you add them below the checksum, they'll stick around in case you do need to recreate.

Comment: @simbabque The classes should be dumped as Perl files. The schema changes but probably not very often. We have really a lot of tables. I want the relationships which fit in the scheme in my question to be generated automatically, but I want also write derived classes with more relationships and more other properties. I don't understand what you mean by "the checksum". I am awaiting for a reply to my question: Can we use `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` for this or do I need to create my own Loader.

Comment: If you look at the auto-generated code that D::C::S::L spits out you'll see that there is a section below the code where you can put custom code. If you rerun the loader, it will keep that custom code. If you change anything above, the checksum will not match and it will abort. // I don't know if you can do what you want without research.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about "hacking" DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader to handle this. Just generate the classes and then add the relationships manually.

Every class that you generate with DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader will contain text at the bottom that looks like this:

```
# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07043 @ 2018-07-09 09:56:55
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:6//4n3Crnz9U/q6GZ0Fwtg

# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
```

As the last comment says, anything that you insert in the file beneath this text will be preserved if you regenerate the class. So you can safely add the relationship information to this section of the file manually and know that it will still be there the next time you regenerate the class.

Don't forget that you'll need to add both sides of the relationship - for example a `has_many` relationship in a parent table and the reciprocal `belongs_to` relationship in the associated child table.